# How to get particular value from SqlCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to store values of `SqlCommand` in string variable and print it on label. Here is my C# code

```
String sq="select fullname,emailId from Registration where RgId= '"+Session["RgId"]+"'";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sq, con); 
con.Open();

SqlDataReader rdr = null;
rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

while(rdr.Read())
{
    string fname = (string)rdr["fullname"];
    string femail=(string)rdr["emailId"];
    Label4.Text = fname; 
    label5.Text=femail;
}

if(rdr!= null)
{
    rdr.Close();
}

con.Close();
```

but instead of printing value it doesn't show value on label. What to do? Is there anything wrong in code?

Comment: Check your session variable - if has been reset then it would be asking for records where the RgId is blank.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables is waiting for you](http://xkcd.com/327/) :-)

Comment: at the very least do the following to protect from injection attacks: `((int)Session["RgId"]).ToString()`

Comment: Session variable `RgId` initialize correctly. Other queries runs properly with same session variable.

Comment: What happens if you set a break point after rdr.Read(), are you actually getting data from the db?

Comment: Do you have try/catch around this code? If yes do you show/log if there is some kind of errors in the code above?

Comment: code doesn't store / retrieve value also it doesn't show error in the code. i haven't set try/ catch in the code

Comment: Just to be sure that your query returns something. Try to comment everything above and just add a line where you set the label4.text with the value of your session variable (However starting to use the debugger could be the easiest way to understand your troubles). Now check if the value printed should effectively return something

Comment: steve i have tried as per your instruction. i have comment `Label4.Text = fname` and and tried to print with `Label4.Text = Session["RgId"].ToString()` but it also not showing anything. now what to do?

Comment: If your query returns multiple rows and the last row happens to have blank/null values that would explain it because your `while` loop is going to loop over every row in the result set. I suspect this problem can be solved with a little judicious debugging to make sure you're generating the SQL you expect and are getting back the results you expect.

Comment: The query i have written need to return single value.

Comment: So your `Session["RgId"].ToString() ` is empty. There is nothing that we can do from here. You need to track what leads to this session variable to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `using` statements when dealing with db access. Things get cleaned up better this way. Since your not using a try/catch in the code provided I would assume your using it in an outer layer or something so I would:

```
        if (Session["RgId"] == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("RgId");

        using (var con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            const string sql = "select fullname,emailId from Registration where RgId = @RgId";

            using (var cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("RdId", SqlDbType.Int) {Value = Session["RgId"]});
                con.Open();
                using (var rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    if (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Label4.Text = (string) rdr["fullname"];
                        label5.Text = (string) rdr["emailId"];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //handle registration not found
                    }
                    rdr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make SQL queries, not concatenate a string, this is very dangerous for your system facilitating SQL injections.

Validate your values before attempting to query and validate the query returns.

```
if (Session["RgId"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["RgId"].ToString()))
{
    String sq = "select fullname,emailId from Registration where RgId = @RgId";

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sq, con);
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@RgId", Convert.ToInt32(Session["RgId"].ToString()));

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    if (rdr != null)
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (rdr["fullname"] != DBNull.Value && rdr["emailId"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                Label4.Text = rdr["fullname"].ToString();
                label5.Text = rdr["emailId"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    if (rdr != null)
    {
        rdr.Close();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Regards,

Andrew

Comment: `ExecuteReader()` always returns an `IDataReader`, so checking for null will always be false.

Comment: Also, see Craig's comment above about using `while`.